# Attribute-based routing and Order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 on ASP.NET 4.5 on .NET 4.6.1.

I have two controllers:

```
FooController
FooIndexController
```

This is because the Index actions for `Foo` are complicated, so I felt it better that they be in their own separate `Controller` classes.

I'm using Attribute-based routing. My version of ASP.NET MVC has the `Order` property on `RouteAttribute`.

I have these actions:

```
class FooController {

    // Returns a view to allow editing of the Foo entity
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/{tenant}/foo/{fooName}", Order=2)]
    public ActionResult Edit(String fooName, FooViewModel model) {
        ...
    }

}

class FooIndexController {

    // Returns a CSV file download listing all of the Foo entities
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/{tenant}/foo/csv", Order=1)]
    public ActionResult IndexCsv() {
        ...
    }
}
```

So while the resource path `bar/foo/csv` would match both route templates, I have specified an explicit `Order=1` for the `IndexCsv` action so it should match that action's route and be done with it, however I still get this yellow-screen-of-death:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.
>
> The request has found the following matching controller types: 
>       MyProject.FooController
>       MyProject.FooIndexController

Why is it disregarding the `Order` property?

I am not using `[RoutePrefix]` or any other attributes on the controllers.

**UPDATE**:

I ran using Phil Haack's Routing Debugger and the weird thing is that it said `POST bar/foo/csv` matched no routes besides `n/a` and `{*catchall}` and that `GET bar/foo/123` didn't match `Edit`'s route either (despite the action being invoked) - I wonder if this secondary issue is a bug in the Route Debugger.

**UPDATE2**:

I'm also not using Global / Convention-based routing either. It's 100% attribute-based routing.

Comment: Interestingly. if you put them in the same controller it works fine and the `IndexCsv()` method is hit (assuming you make it `[HttpGet]`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: `RouteAttribute` order precedence works using same action method name with different relative paths. But if the action method names are different, route constraint should be used, e.g. `[Route("~/{tenant}/foo/{fooName:string}", Order=2)]`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, The constraint does not appear necessary. The `Order` value is respected correctly with different action names if they are in the same controller, but when in different controllers, the exact same methods throw the error as OP has indicated

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'll see what happens if I try a min-length route constraint for `Edit` (as `fooName` will always be longer than 3 characters).